# Geometry Proof: Convex Quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

A quadrilateral $ABCD$ is formed from four distinct points (called the vertices), no three of which are collinear, and from the segments $AB$, $CB$, $CD$, and $DA$ (called the sides), which have no intersections except at those endpoints labeled by the same letter. The notation for this quadrilateral is not unique- e.g., quadrilateral $ABCD$ = quadrilateral $CBAD$.

Two vertices that are endpoints of a side are called adjacent; otherwise the two vertices are called opposite. The remaining pair of segments $AC$ and $BD$ formed from the four points are called diagonals of the quadrilateral; they may or may not intersect at some fifth point. If $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are the vertices of quadrilateral $ABCD$ such that $Y$ is adjacent to both $X$ and $Z$, then angle $XYZ$ is called an angle of the quadrilateral; if $W$ is the fourth vertex, then angle $XWZ$ and angle $XYZ$ are called opposite angles.

The quadrilaterals of main interest are the **convex** ones. By definition, they are the quadrilaterals such that each pair of opposite sides, e.g., $AB$ and $CD$, has the property that $CD$ is contained in one of the half-planes bounded by the line through $A$ and $B$, and $AB$ is contained in one of the half-planes bounded by the line through $C$ and $D$.

**a)**   Using Pasch's theorem, prove that if one pair of opposite sides has this property, then so does the other pair of opposite sides.

**b)**    Prove, using the crossbar theorem, that the following are equivalent:

1. The quadrilateral is convex.
2. Each vertex of the quadrilateral lies in the interior of the opposite angle.
3. The diagonals of the quadrilateral meet.

I can’t seem to make sense of **a)** at all. For **b)** I approached it in this way - I made three separate proofs:

1. If the quadrilateral is convex, then the diagonals of the quadrilateral meet.

**Proof:**  Assume quadrilateral $ABCD$ is a convex quadrilateral. We have to prove that segment $AC$ and segment $BD$ have a point in common. By the
    definition of a convex quadrilateral, $C$ is in the interior of angle
    $DAB$. Hence, ray $AC$ intersects segment $BD$ at some point $E$ (by the
    crossbar theorem). Therefore, $E$ is the required intersection point
    of the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$.

2. If the diagonals of the quadrilateral meet, then each vertex of the quadrilateral lies in the interior of the opposite angle.

**Proof:**

3. If each vertex of the quadrilateral lies in the interior of the opposite angle, then the quadrilateral is convex.

**Proof:**

I’m also confused over the proofs for 2. And 3.. Theorems and axioms that might be helpful:

*Pasch’s Theorem*: If $A$, $B$, and $C$ are distinct points and $l$ is any line intersecting $AB$ in a point between $A$ and $B$, then $l$ also intersects either $AC$, or $BC$. If $C$ does not lie on $l$, then $l$ does not intersect both $AC$ and $BC$.

*Interior an angle*: Given an angle $\angle CAB$, deﬁne a point $D$ to be in the interior of $\angle CAB$ if $D$ is on the same side of Ray $AC$ as $B$ and if $D$ is also on the same side of Ray $AB$ as $C$. Thus, the interior of an angle is the intersection of two half-planes.

*Crossbar Theorem*: If ray $AD$ is between ray $AC$ and ray $AB$, then ray $AD$ intersects segment $BC$.

Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In a possible attempt to explain **a)**, let us focus solely on a single angle, say angle $A$. Similarly, draw tangent lines extending from the two adjacent sides, namely $AB$ and $AD$. Assuming $A\neq180$ (which we can, because it would cause $ABCD$ to be a triangle), $AB$ and $AD$ are not parallel.

This means that they meet at $A$ and continue, getting further apart as they go. If $A \lt 180$, meaning $ABCD$ is convex, $AB$ and $AD$ continue away from the shape, not intersecting any sides.

However, if $A \gt 180$, $AB$ and $AD$ enter the interior or $ABCD$ after intersecting at $A$. As the lines are infinite and the quadrilateral is not, the lines must at some point leave the shape. As two lines can only meet at a single point, and will not intersect themselves, they must leave the shape through one of the other two sides *(Note Pasch's Theorem).*

As both $AB$ and $AD$ are equally dependent on the angle of $A$, it is not possible for only one of the two lines to split one of the other sides.